# How to add a comment with a referral to the user whose username has a space inside the string? (@)

Tags: support, users, comments

Lets say an user "John Doe" commented under some answer post.
How to write a comment that will contain a referral to John Doe's username? (referral by using the @ symbol).
I've tried:

@(John Doe)

@John-Doe

@JohnDoe

Unfortunately none of them worked for some reason.

Comment: See also: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@autocompleting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106450/147520) was implemented some time ago for comments. You should be able to type @ followed by the first character of the username and you'll be presented with a list of suitable usernames to tab through.

[image: @autocomplete in action]

In the example above BillWeiss real username is Bill Weiss so just removing the space(s) should also work.

Comment: Should the autocompletion work when I reply to an user answer and I refer to the user, who posted the answer? i.e. here: http://superuser.com/questions/401933/can-a-digital-photo-store-both-dpi-and-ppi-values

Comment: Comments to answers are automatically notified to the person who wrote the answer to @'s are not needed.

Comment: Thank you lain, you're right. Why would I use the @ syntax if I can just write the user's username by hand. I've overthought that... or maybe not. What do you think about if the syntax would work in this case also? My thoughts: typing the username through @ is faster than doing it manually and the auto completion ensures that I won't make a typo in the username. Also, I think it's more pleasant for the receiver if he/she sees his/her username in the answer / comment.